# connection to localhost failed react project

Tags: reactjs, frontend, localhost

I recieved this on localhost:3000 while working on a front end using create-react-app.
I have tried clearing cache and browserdata, adding .env file and define port 3000 there, putting https=true and npm run in package.json, nothing worked. It started off fine and then not displaying anything on Edge, Chrome and FF. Please help

```
WebSocketClient @   WebSocketClient.js:16
initSocket  @   socket.js:24
(anonymous) @   socket.js:48
```

Comment: did you add **WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0** to `.env` file ?

Comment: Please add full error.

Comment: that exactly what I got in dev tools @DevAKS

Comment: and yes I added the .env file with the  WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 doesnt work @monim

Answer (score 0):

from trying everything desperately to nothing working, i ended up uninstall react and node and reinstall that globally. For some reason it worked well.